# How does my browser know which headerlink is active?

Tags: html, css, header

I support the webmasters for my school district. The webmasters basically use the CMS, Umbraco, to manage the school websites.

One of the websites has a unique horizontal navigation bar in that it is colored, whereas, the others are black text and gray background. This particular site has yellow text and a green background. Particularly for the placeholders (that is, the links that contain drop downs menus). There are three header links in particular that have black text and green background (Home. Family Resource Center and Media Center). As you could guess, this doesn't look uniform.

So I thought the solution would be to go into the css file and tell the links to be green yellow text with green background but doing this effects the **Home** active header link. For instance, when you go onto a page, the home button is automatically active and active links have yellow backgrounds. So making the change I stated above, makes a solid yellow tab because the text is yellow and the background is yellow.

Then I thought to add "a:active" to the code so that I can separate the active link from the unactive links but the "a" (link) line of code seems to override it or maybe I'm not setting up the code to where the browser can understand that the Home button is active and the other are not.

Here is the code: `https://jsfiddle.net/so23v245/`

```
<html></html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please post a jsFiddle so we can see the phenomena , because you just wrote the book of eli There :p

Comment: You are on the right track, beside that CSS does not know which page is active. `:active` is a selector for the most current activated (clicked) element. Once the page reloads (or the location is changed) this highlighting is gone. You need server side help to identify the currently active link, to be able to append an additional class like `.active` to it. You should ask a question regarding the CMS system in use, how to identify the current navigation link and add a css class to it. Your question like it is is very unlikely to be answered. Good luck.

Comment: @moolsbytheway lol!

Comment: The link is https://jsfiddle.net/so23v245/

Comment: so what are your privileges ? do you have access to server side of the site ?

Comment: I do. I have access to all the files that make up the page.

Comment: Any other help that you can give me?